# switch between buttons in specific worksheet and loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to create my first macro in VBA, I try to make simple macro which will switch button in each minute to present different data.
Right now I'm really frustrated, because each time I change something I receive different error, for sure I have issues with references to worksheet which I want to choose. Currently I get error "loop without do" and when I'm deleting loop, I get compile error "expected end with".

Please find my "work" below, and please let me how to make it work.

```
Public Sub Switch()
Do
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ControlBoard.Activate
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = False
    Application.Wait Now("00:01:00")
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = False
     Application.Wait Now("00:01:00")

End With
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = True
     Application.Wait Now("00:01:00")
End With
Loop

End Sub
```

Ok, now I change it a bit and I get Run time error 13 (type mismatch) and I get debug on first line - Application.Wait Now("00:01:00")

```
Public Sub Switch()
Dim DashBoard As Sheet3
Do

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = False
    Application.Wait Now("00:01:00")
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = False
     Application.Wait Now("00:01:00")

End With
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = True
     Application.Wait Now("00:01:00")
End With
Loop
End Sub
```

I have solved type mismatch by adding + TimeValue
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
But slicer doesn't behave, as I want it. It gets me at beginning ("XX") true but further on it ticking ("YY") true and ("XX") still remains, as true, can you help me to solve it?

OK I have solved this by putting True statement in first line, it's freeze from time to time but it works, can you let me know, if it's possible to add switch off key, to avoid esc+esc exit?

```
Public Sub Switch()
Dim DashBoard As Sheet3
Do

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = False
     Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project1")
    .SlicerItems("ZZ").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("XX").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("YY").Selected = False
     Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
End With
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: you said that you are getting different errors. so you know that there is more than one error possible.  .... why would you make us guess which errors you are getting?

Comment: By how I see it, you are trying to automate updating slicers correct?

Comment: I'm trying to switch between buttons, so in each one minute will change projected data on dashboard.